# Smart ways to handle boolean and string

Tags: python, parsing, boolean, boolean-expression

I want to know what is the smart way to handle Boolean and string together. Let say I have the following Boolean expression `"~a"` (not a) with respect to a trace `T = ["ab", "b", "a", ""]`. The evaluation result is `R = [False, True, False, True]` because it must not have a. but while parsing if I have `True` instead of `a` then the trace will change. I have written the condition in python like this,

```
    if op == '~':
        if p == True:
            return False
        elif p == False:
            return True
        if p in T[i]:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Is there any succinct and better way to write this? (p can be a string or a boolean value) I tried to short it as it is a simple condition, but I'm facing the error that says string and boolean do not match.

Comment: What did you do to trigger that error? It's better to write `if p is True` than `if p == True`, but it's not an error, whatever the type of `p` might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let see... do you mean something like this?

```
def setter(data, T):
    if data[0] == "~":
        data = data[1:]
        return [data not in t for t in T]
    else:
        return [data in t for t in T]
    
setter("a", ["ab", "b", "a", ""])
```